# Datepicker popup is not dispalying when I use visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Date Picker is not working for my below code, it is displaying javascript error when I tried to see using F12 in IE. JS error

> "Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null
>   reference"

. Please help me to find out problem. But one strange is happening here, when I use other input date field(by default from object temp field) this is also working.

please help me ASAP..............

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="testDateSecItem" rendered="{!showtestDate}">
<apex:outputLabel Test Date</apex:outputLabel>                            
<apex:outputPanel >
<div class="requiredInput"> 
<div class="requiredBlock"></div>
<apex:inputText value="{!testDate}" size="10" id="testDateId" label="Start Date" onfocus="DatePicker.pickDate(true, this , false);" required="true" onchange="setTabUnsavedChangesOnForm();return false"/> &nbsp;[
<apex:commandLink onclick="fillStartDate('{!TODAY()}');return false;" id="cmdLink"> 
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd/MM/yyyy}" style="color:#0070d2; text-decoration:none" id="outtxt">
<apex:param value="{!TODAY()}" id="dateId"/>
</apex:outputText>
</apex:commandLink> &nbsp;]
</div>
<apex:message for="testDateId" style="color: #cc0000;"></apex:message>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Comment: Can you add a link to the Datepicker library and also be more specific about which browser version you tried? IE behavior can vary pretty dramatically even just going back to 8. Have you tried on other browsers?

Comment: Thank-you for sharing comments. I tried this chrome and IE11. Issue was happened in both browsers. Please elaborate which link I needs to add for data picker library,